# searching for the minimum of complex calculations

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Fictional example. The actual calculations are more complicated.

```
n <- 0.3
test <- data.frame(used = c(1.545, 0.125, 0.0548), product = c(3.56, -1.589, 0.878))

test <- test %>% mutate (
  product.scale = n * product,
  p.diff = used - product.scale
)

wynik =  nrow (test[test$p.diff > 0,])
```

How to find the (smallest) value at which the "wynik" variable becomes 2.
In excel I would use "Goal Seek".

The second part of the task is to prepare a data.frame (n value and "wynik" value) for the selected set of n (for example n = c (1, 2, 2.5, 2.8, 3.7)

Comment: Have you tried `uniroot`?

Comment: I haven't used it yet, but it looks promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the brute force method by testing a number of runs at different parameter values for n.

```
test <- data.frame(used = c(1.545, 0.125, 0.0548), product = c(3.56, -1.589, 0.878))
params <- seq(0, 4, by = .1) # can try even smaller than 0.1 steps if you wanted
wynik <- rep(NA, length(params)) # initialize results object
for(i in 1:length(params)){
  n <- params[i]
  wynik[i] <- length(which(test$used - n * test$product > 0))
}
cbind(params,wynik)
 #params wynik
 #[1,]    0.0       3
 #[2,]    0.1       2
 #[3,]    0.2       2
 #[4,]    0.3       2
 #[5,]    0.4       2
 #[6,]    0.5       1
 #[7,]    0.6       1
 #...     ...       ...
```